# How get all combinations at python with repeat

Tags: python-3.x, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

Code example

```
from itertools import *
from collections import Counter
from tqdm import *
#for i in tqdm(Iterable):
for i in combinations_with_replacement(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'], 8):
    b = (''.join(i))
    if b == '72637721':
        print (b)
```

when i try profuct i have

```
    for i in product(['1','2','3','4','5','7','6','8'], 8):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How can i get all combinations ? ( i was belive it before not test , so now all what i was do wrong)

i was read about combinations_with_replacement return all , but how i see it's lie

i use python 3.8

Out put for ask

> 11111111 11111112 11111113 11111114 11111115 11111116 11111117
> 11111118 11111122 11111123 11111124 11111125 11111126 11111127
> 11111128 11111133 11111134 11111135 11111136 11111137 11111138
> 11111144 11111145 11111146 11111147 11111148 11111155 11111156
> 11111157 11111158 11111166 11111167 11111168 11111177 11111178
> 11111188 11111222 11111223 11111224 11111225 11111226 11111227
> 11111228 11111233 11111234 11111235 11111236 11111237 11111238
> 11111244 11111245 11111246 11111247 11111248 11111255 11111256
> 11111257 11111258 11111266 11111267 11111268 11111277 11111278
> 11111288

what it start give at end

> 56666888 56668888 56688888 56888888 58888888 77777777 77777776
> 77777778 77777766 77777768 77777788 77777666 77777668 77777688
> 77777888 77776666 77776668 77776688 77776888 77778888 77766666
> 77766668 77766688 77766888 77768888 77788888 77666666 77666668
> 77666688 77666888 77668888 77688888 77888888 76666666 76666668
> 76666688 76666888 76668888 76688888 76888888 78888888 66666666
> 66666668 66666688 66666888 66668888 66688888 66888888 68888888
> 88888888

more cleare think it how it be count from 1111 1111 to 8888 8888 ( but for characters , so this why i use try do it at permutation/combine with repitions...
it miss some possible combinations of that symbols.

as  example what i try do , make all permutatuion of possible variants of hex numbers , like from 0 to F , but make it not only for them , make this possible for any charater.

this only at example ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']
this can be ['a','b','x','c','d','g','r','8'] etc.

Comment: what is your input and desired output?

Comment: Input is as example 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

i need get all combination from 11111111 to 88888888
othe example from 1111 1111 to FFFF FFFF expect all variants like 111ffad7 or 123fabcd
script what i post is say it self what it try do by this cheek if b == '72637721':

Comment: Can you include the input and expected output for a smaller example ? Does 8 specify the length of the string ?

Comment: Can you please use the question section to add your details: Input, desired output. What does 11111111 to 88888888 mean. Is it just a repeat of these numbers for the length of the list?

Comment: i am cannot put al output , by reason it is to huge :/ But litle example of out put i add.
how you see it for some reasone miss some variants :/

Comment: What should be the answer when the input is (['1', '2', '3', '4'], 5) ?

Comment: irrespective of what i tried, I cannot find the value of `72637721` in the list of `['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']` Maybe I have to write my own algo to do this

Comment: But this is strange, it most work.

Comment: need use itertools.product

Answer (score 1):

solition is use itertools.product instead combinations_with_replacement

```
from itertools import *
for i in product(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'],repeat = 8):
    b = (''.join(i))
    if b == '72637721':
        print (b)
```

:

```
itertools.product ('ABCD', 'ABCD') AA AB AC AD BA BB BC BD CA CB CC CD DA DB DC DD # full multiplication with duplicates and mirrored pairs 

itertools.permutations ('ABCD', 2) -> AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC # full multiplication without duplicates and mirrored pairs 

itertools.combinations_with_replacement ('ABCD', 2) -> AA AB AC AD BB BC BD CC CD DD # no mirror pairs with duplicates 

itertools.combinations ('ABCD', 2) -> AB AC AD BC BD CD # no mirrored pairs and no duplicates
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated code that will print you all the combinations. It does not matter if your list has strings and numbers.

To ensure that you are doing a combination only for the specific number of elements, I recommend that you do:

```
comb_list = [1, 2, 3, 'a']
comb_len = len(comb_list)
```

and replace the line with:

```
comb = combinations_with_replacement(comb_list, comb_len)


from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
comb = combinations_with_replacement([1, 2, 3, 'a'], 4)
for i in list(comb): 
    print (''.join([str(j) for j in i]))
```

This will result as follows:

```
1111
1112
1113
111a
1122
1123
112a
1133
113a
11aa
1222
1223
122a
1233
123a
12aa
1333
133a
13aa
1aaa
2222
2223
222a
2233
223a
22aa
2333
233a
23aa
2aaa
3333
333a
33aa
3aaa
aaaa
```

I don't know what you are trying to do. Here's an attempt to start a dialogue to get to the final answer:

```
samples = [1,2,3,4,5,'a','b']
len_samples = len(samples)
for elem in samples:
    print (str(elem)*len_samples)
```

The output of this will be as follows:

```
1111111
2222222
3333333
4444444
5555555
aaaaaaa
bbbbbbb
```

Is this what you want? If not, explain your question section what you expect as an output.

Comment: I need combinations of all possible vatiants of as simple example from 1 to 8
if there was only 1 to 8 , but i need them for any words.
this was most do that function , but it not do what expected.
Ok think if i do it from with 0 
so it be from 00000000 to 88888888

Comment: If see at ourput at start all good but at and it give ( see update at qustion)

Comment: I see it now. Trying to find a better way to iterate thru this and push the output

Comment: Yes and if see result from start all working , but at some steep it stop working as expected , by doc's that functions most reaturn all how if it be simple counting by number += 1 ( or at c++  ++1)