# How do I create same numbers patterns list in Python?

Tags: python

I want to create a pattern of numbers which repeat the same number thrice or twice.

Example: 111(and here 1), 2221 3331 4441 5551... And when it reaches 9991, the next output should be 1112 2222 3332.

And finally another combination after the first one has finished should be like 1122 2211 3322 4422 2244. 5599. I need two same numbers twice here.

Comment: What happened when you tried to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64080339/how-get-all-combinations-at-python-with-repeat/64080679

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution. One loop to increment right value. Inner loop to increment repeating left value

```py
for i in range(1,10):
    for j in range(1,10):
        print(f"{str(j) * 3}{i}")
```

Output:

```py
1111
2221
3331
4441
5551
6661
7771
8881
9991
1112
2222
3332
...(You get the point)
```